# Famo.us Maximum Touch Points (Windows 8 + Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-8, multi-touch, famo.us

I'm doing discovery on developing a multi-touch web app on an [Ideum multitouch table](http://ideum.com/touch-tables/platform-coffee/) which has capacity for 46 touch points.

I don't have direct access to the Ideum table yet, but was able to test a [codepen](http://codepen.io/typ90/pen/yybQrW) that I adapted from another SO question on both a 5 point Windows 8 machine, as well as my Google Nexus 5 (got up to 10 points) using TouchSync:

```
var touchSync = new TouchSync({touchLimit: 46}, function () {
    return position;
});
```

When I had someone with physical access to the table attempt 10+ touch points, they were stopped at 10.

I'm wondering before I continue if Famo.us can support more than 10 touch events, or if this is just a browser limitation with Chrome on Windows 8.

**Does anybody have any insights on Famo.us's limitations when it comes to number of touch points?**

Comment: Note: I haven't yet been able to test "navigator.maxTouchPoints" on the device. I will update tomorrow when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that will specifically prevent one from using multiple touch points within a Famous application beyond the `touchLimit` of the `TouchTracker`.  That said, I have not tried to develop an app that uses more than 2 touch points at a time.

**Side Note:** When you are developing, I would pay specific attention to the Famous `appMode` behavior.  When testing the 10+ touch points, you may want to try setting:

`Engine.setOptions({appMode: false});`

This will prevent the following code from from executing:

```
function initialize() {
    // prevent scrolling via browser
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, true);

    addRootClasses();
}
```

While I do not think this will have an impact, I will restate that I have not developed an app with more than 2 touch points and is something I would want to understand.

You may also want to check out:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=316085